# How come shares of GME or AMC are not available to borrow for short selling during a short squeeze?

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities

The principle of a short squeeze is that it makes it difficult to *buy* stock, so that people who want to cover their shorts have to pay a premium and make the price go higher. Conversely, that should mean that people are holding the stock and not selling it, and so it should not be difficult to find shares to borrow for short selling.

Yet my broker, which should be reasonably big (Schwab), claims that there are no shares available for AMC, GME, BB, NOK, BBBY... Even if I ask for one single share:

"Your request to enter a short sale cannot currently be processed, as there are not sufficient shares available. (DO3094)"

I can short TSLA if I want, so my account is set up properly.

Comment: The same reason Ferraris are not available to borrow - _nobody is willing to borrow you one_...

Answer (score 1):

A short squeeze does not make it more difficult to buy stock. It merely makes the cost of buying the stock more.

Just because many people are holding the stock and not selling it, that does not mean that those shares are all available for lending. Cash accounts cannot lend shares.

Under normal circumstances, stocks become non borrowable.  It's not a rare occurrence.  However, the GME short squeeze is not normal circumstances.  Robinhood is undercapitalized and due to the events of the past week, it needed a capital infusion to continue operation, let alone survive.  That's the reason that they placed restrictions on trading shares of AMC, BB, BBBY, EXPR, GME, KOSS, NAKD, and NOK. FWIW, it's a Mickey Mouse operation and it eludes me why people trade there when far more and far better service is available at major brokers, also with no commissions.

Comment: My understanding is that cash account can lend shares if they allow their brokers... And 
I understand that Robinhood has issues, but that doesn't explain why Schwab would not find stock to borrow. Could that mean that all the stock available has been used for short selling already?

Comment: My understanding is that  cash account cannot lend shares. If one can sign an exemption allowing lending, I doubt that many cash account holders are doing so because they tend to be either less sophisticated or more conservative investors. So the amount of shares available becomes a diminishing return situation. Just thinking out loud but I suspect that a lot of people may be buying odd lots and I wonder if a broker wants to get involved loaning shares from a dozen accounts (perhaps this is nonsense since stock is in street name). If the shares are hard to borrow, none are available.

Comment: To speak more plainly, **'robinhood' is a f###ing joke**.  Apart from anything else, why, in the name of God, would anyone ever use a *stock broker* with a joke name?  The whole thing is mystifying.

Comment: @Fattie - Stop this pussyfooting around.  Tell us how you really feel ;->).  Over the past few years I've read about a sh*tload of legitimate complaints about Robinhood as well as a series of SEC fines for their miserable operations.  I can't believe that a game like phone app is a good enough reason to accept totally inferior service.

Comment: It just utterly, utterly baffles me. (1) They are no cheaper!!  WTF.  (2) Their "shtick" that they are "for the people" (or, something) is so ridiculous it's not even funny (a bit like corporate "greenwashing" as they say).  (3) In the name of everything Holy, when trying to decide on someone to, I dunno, ***look after your money***, wouldn't you use more rational decision points than "funny name!" etc. My God!